# appending onto sql results each iteration

Tags: mysql

Good afternoon all, I have a situation where I need to continue to append MySQL results onto existing results after each iteration of a parent loop.  An example of what I'm working with would look like:

```
while ($record = mysql_fetch_row($result,MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
   $result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Products WHERE id='".$record['target']."'");
}
```

I'm looking to append onto $result2 for each iteration of the 'while' loop so that I can have a complete list in $result2 that can later be processed.  How can I accomplish this task?

Thanks,
Dave

Comment: Wait, are you looking for an update to your code because the second query doesn't execute properly, or are you looking to store many mysql_query results in an array and then go through them later?

Comment: There may be an easy way to do this.  Does `$record` contain anything else other than the field `target`?  If it does contain other fields, are they used at all?

Comment: Yes DiMono, I'm looking to update the code above to continue to append mysql query results to $results2.

Comment: Yes Jrod to both of your questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use the `IN` method, instead of running an unknown amount of queries which can really slow your application? And then getting all the results in 1 query. Like:

```
$ids = "";
while ($record = mysql_fetch_row($result,MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    if( $record['target'] )
    {
        $ids .= "," . $record['target']
    }
    else
    {
        $ids = $record['target'];
    }
}
$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Products WHERE id IN (".$ids.")");
```

Now `$result2` contains all the Products from the previous `$result`;

More information

1. [MySQL IN](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-in-clause.htm)

Comment: This is a better solution than the one I posted. I'd came back to create an IN clause query.

Comment: Although, this isn't recursive (which probably isn't a requirement)

Comment: You don't want recursive queries, that means your doing something wrong. I think we should be provided with more information to answer it correctly.

Comment: If it's building a tree-like structure then you pretty much need recursive, unless of course you pull all everything and building from there

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you're looking for.

```
   <?
    $resultSetQueue     = Array();
    $results             = Array();
    $resultSetQueue[]    = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM Products WHERE <Initial Criteria>");

    for($i = 0; $i < count($resultSetQueue); $i++){
        $in = "";
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultSetQueue[$i])){
           $in                 .=  $row['target']. ",";
           $results[]           =   $row;
        }
        $resultSetQueue[]       =   mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM Products WHERE id IN (". substr($in, 0, strlen($in) - 2). ")");
?>
```

Every query result set is added to the result set queue, processing it when its time comes in the for($i... loop.

Be careful though. This has the potential to loop indefinitely (until the memory usage limit is reached).

Edit: Better query method - using IN.